# Google SignIn denied firebase

Tags: java, android

**the app says authentication failed (haha) even after giving permission from *firebase.*
kindly look into my mainactivity below.**
In tutorials the sign in code is different and i guess old, i have added sha1 in firebase and gradle is connected perfectly.
Few commands decribed on firebase and developer.google are confusing.
Please help! started android 2 weeks ago.

```
import android.content.Intent;   
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements           View.OnClickListener {

private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 123;
private static final String TAG = "Play";
GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button) .setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    //updateUI(currentUser);
}


private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}


private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //updateUI(user);
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "haha",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //updateUI(null);
                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
}




@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
            // ...
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.sign_in_button:
            signIn();
            break;

}
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be due to wrong client ID

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id)) // here
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

You can get the server's client ID only from Google's developer console from Credentials option: https://console.developers.google.com/

Another thing is check if Authentication via Google is enabled in 
Firebase Console -> Authentication

Comment: could you please explain me in brief, I went to the console as you said but I could not find credential options.
and authentication on _firebase_ is *enabled.*

Comment: There will be an id automatically created in credentials.

Comment: Are you sure if you looked in the same project in credentials console?

Comment: OH ! yes. Sorry. 
And yes I have it, console.developer API page-bottom Oauth section.
but how do I implement it?

Comment: I did it   :) your help is appreciated

Comment: Great! If this answer solved your issue then please upvote and select this as the answer. Happy coding :)